# When the younger Lee Lim killed the present Lee Lim in the past, why didn't he die in 2020?

Tags: the-king-eternal-monarch

In an episode of *The King: Eternal Monarch*, Lee Lim and Lee Gon go to the past (1994). Once there, Lee Lim meets with his younger self and tells him that the coup will fail if he doesn't kill the crown prince first. But the younger Lee Lim doesn't believe him and kills him. Thus I had thought that the 2020 Lee Lim is dead and wouldn't be coming back to 2020. But he came back to 2020 like nothing happened. Why is this the case?